# Passing lambdas to std::thread and calling class methods

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, lambda

I'm having a bit of trouble using std::thread together with lambdas. I have a method TheMethod where I should use std::thread to parallelize some function calls to methods in the same class.

I define a lambda function, and try to pass it as follows to the std::thread instance I create:

```
auto functor = 
   [this](const Cursor& c, size_t& result) ->void {result = classMethod(c);};

size_t a;
Cursor cursor = someCursor();

std::thread t1(functor, cursor, a);

t1.join();
```

Unfortunately, the compiler gives me:

```
  /usr/include/c++/4.8/functional:1697:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<TheMethod...
```

I tried a lot of combinations in the lambda definition, and in the way of calling the std::thread constructor, but I get the same error always. The thread library is included, I link pthread too.

Thanks for hints!

Comment: Say `std::thread t1(functor, std::ref(cursor), std::ref(a));`

Comment: Indeed, now it compiles. Thanks @KerrekSB !

Comment: you should mark the anwer as valid, so next time people will catch that this is the good answer

Comment: How can I do that? I only see the option to vote up next to Kerrek SBs answer. Sorry, I'm kind of new here.

Answer (score 51):

You can use std::ref to pass the parameters by reference:

```
std::thread t1(functor, std::ref(cursor), std::ref(a))
```

You could also capture the parameters by reference in the lambda itself:

```
size_t a;
Cursor cursor = someCursor();
std::thread t1([&] {a = classMethod(cursor);});
t1.join();
```

Comment: I do want to warn that if `t1` is detached and the main thread exits, calling a class method by reference without using std::ref is potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the objects `cursor` and `a` are passed by value to the constructor of thread. The functor takes a reference to the local copies of the newly created thread and not on the objects you expected them to be.

Hence, as answered by "alexk7", you should use `std::ref` or if you want to capture them pass by reference.