# Thread Simplicity

Tags: c++, multithreading

(This is a MUCH simpler version of something bigger i'm trying to do.) 
Rather then doing all of this procedure to print hello three times:

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadarg) {
 cout << "hello world" << endl;
}

main:
 data thread_data[3];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, PrintHello, NULL);

for(i=0; i < blocks; i++)
  pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
```

Is there an equivalent way to print hello world three times without jumping to a function?  Can I get a simple example if there is?

Something like this:

```
void *PrintHello(void *threadarg) {
 cout << "hello world" << endl;
}

main:
 data thread_data[3];

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
  rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, NULL, NULL);

cout << "hello world" << endl;

for(i=0; i < blocks; i++)
  pthread_join(threads[i], &status);
```

My issue is that I need my threads to use a lot of structs and variables in a project.  It's going to take a while to set up the pass by references, but I think I have no choice.

Comment: I'd suggest picking just one of the `[c]` and `[c++]` tags as appropriate.

Comment: With standard c++ threads you could use a lambda function.

Comment: `cout << "hello world\nhello world\nhello world\n";`

Comment: Also, if you are using C++, consider using `std::thread` instead of `pthread`.

Comment: @NathanOliver My issue is that I need my threads to use a lot of structs and variables in a project. It's going to take a while to set up the pass by references, but I think I have no choice.

Comment: your last solution would only print hello world (OR DO MULTIPLE SET OF TASKS) only once.    std::thread first (void); 
  std::thread second (void); cout << "hello world" << endl;  -only prints hello world 1 time

Comment: This really sounds like a XY problem.  Why do you need threads to print out hello world three times?

Comment: i don't it's a simplified issue of many things I need to do

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I'm not sure how that would work exactly

Comment: @djent [like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581319/1413395) for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I wish I didnt have to type in a bunch of code within the lambda, but otherwise thats a perfect solution. thanks